# How to get saved arrayList from preferences

Tags: java, android, arrays

I try to get my saved records from sharedPreferences, but i cant. Always nothing show.

In `LostDialogFragment` i save the array, i debugging this and this always save data. I get References from MainGameFragment

```
 public void saveArray() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("user_and_score", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.addAll(MainGameFragment.LEADERBOARDUSER);
    edit.putStringSet("user_and_score", set);
    edit.apply();
}
```

Here is reference in `MainGameFragment`

```
 public static ArrayList<String> LEADERBOARDUSER = new ArrayList<>();
```

And in `SettingsFragment` i try get saved Array

```
 private ArrayList<String> leaderBoardList = new ArrayList<>();


case LEADER_BOARD:
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("user_and_score", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
            edit.putStringSet("user_and_score", set);
            set.addAll(leaderBoardList);
            edit.apply();
            adapter = new CustomAdapterForSettingsFragment(leaderBoardList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            break;
```

My question is how to get saved array ?

Or i didnt save. I debugging now and no one is saved, Help me with save array in Shared too

Comment: You need to use the method [getStringSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet(java.lang.String, java.util.Set<java.lang.String>)) to get your saved set from shared preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your saving the Set problem,Try the followings:-
1.) Give some different key to save your set, like

```
 edit.putStringSet("your_set", set);
```

2.) Use

```
 edit.commit()
```

And to get your Set, try the following :-

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("user_and_score", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Set<String> newSet = prefs.getStringSet("your_set", new HashSet<String>());
```

By doing this, you can get your saved set in newSet.
Thanks!!!

Comment: I save everything but i cant retrieve

Comment: Have you tried using getStringSet() as I stated above.

Comment: Everything work perfectly now. I Will accep your answer, thanks so much :)

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here [Save ArrayList to SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences). 
Also I think you have a problem in

```
edit.apply();
```

try

```
edit.commit();
```

Comment: While the link may answer the OP's question, it is not recommended to write link-only answers. In the future if the link gets modified, the answer will not be useful to future visitors. Instead post the relevant snippets that can answer the question in your answer and add the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
}
```

Set the values

```
List<String> leaderBoardList   = new ArrayList<>();

Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonText = gson.toJson(leaderBoardList);
prefsEditor.putString("key", jsonText);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Retrieve the values

```
List<String> leaderBoardList   = new ArrayList<>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonText = Prefs.getString("key", null);
String[] text = gson.fromJson(jsonText, String[].class);  //EDIT: gso to gson

leaderBoardList  = Arrays.asList(text);
leaderBoardList  = new ArrayList(leaderBoardList );
```

Comment: when i try retrieve i have bug:
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with shared preferences, I could not get a previously saved String.

A solution that worked for me was to get the SharedPrefs instance via the PreferenceManager:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
```

And then get the String Set:

```
Set<String> set = sharedPref.getStringSet("your_set", new HashSet<String>());
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is:

1) convert your list in to `JsonArray` say jsonArrayPref

2) save jsonArrayPref.toString() to shared preferences

3) when ever you want that List then get the jsonArrayPref from the preferences in the form of string

4) and then convert it in to `JsonArray` and render you data and use it